# How to display only the tweetTimestamp using jtweetsanywhere?

Tags: jquery

Has anyone got any experience using jtweetsanywhere plugin?Im trying to display only the timestamp of the tweets.At the moment I get all the attributes like the retweeter as well.This is the code im using.

```
$('#tweetFeed').jTweetsAnywhere({
                username: 'username',
                count: 1,
                showTweetFeed: {
                    showProfileImages: false,
                    showUserScreenNames: false,
                    showUserFullNames: false,
                    showActionReply: false,
                    showActionRetweet: false,
                    showActionFavorite: false,
                    showTwitterBird: false,
                    showTimestamp: {
                        refreshInterval: 15
                    }
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the configuration options (and their default values) that can be set when invoking jTweetsAnywhere:

```
showProfileImages: null
showUserScreenNames: null
showUserFullNames: false
showActionReply: false
showActionRetweet: false
showActionFavorite: false
showTwitterBird: true
showTimestamp: true
showSource: false
showGeoLocation: true
showInReplyTo: true
```

if you want to hide the retweeter you have to overwrite the `tweetRetweeterDecorator` inside the configuration options:

```
tweetRetweeterDecorator: function()
{
    return '';
}
```